# Informative prior for a binomial proportion close to one (or zero)

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior

I want to do inference on a binomial proportion, which I have reason to believe a priori is close to one. Let's say my prior expectation is 0.98. I'd like to do incremental updating of my beliefs as Bayesian inference allows me to, and I'd like to be able to calculate quantities such as the (posterior) probability that the binomial parameter is greater than 0.95. The question is how to parameterise my prior such that my posterior inferences are not invalidated by a beta distribution with a parameter less than 1. This would happen if I, for instance, observed 10 data points all of which were successes. In this case I'd have a posterior which was:

$\theta | data \sim Beta(\alpha + 10, \beta)$.

To ensure this behaved in a sensible way, I'd need to use a prior effective sample size of at least 50, which feels somewhat limiting as my prior beliefs might not be quite this strong. Can I resolve this quandary while retaining simple (not expensive) iterative posterior inference? Am I being limited by the choice of the conjugate prior?

Comment: "prior effective sample size" is new to me, interesting concept:  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3081791/

Comment: Why are you considering that the posterior inference is invalidated by such a Beta ?

Comment: Because it's J shaped. Inference is not invalid precisely but the distribution has some odd properties, such as its mode at 1, as well as many more derived properties. I can add a specific use case if it helps, but I thought it was accepted that Beta distributions like this had undesirable behaviour

Comment: Please clarify the question by listing what properties you want the prior and posterior to have.